# Ollama GPU Support

Tags: llm, llama-2, gpu, text-generation

I've just installed Ollama in my system and chatted with it a little.
Unfortunately, the response time is very slow even for lightweight models like tinyllama.
It seems that Ollama is in CPU-only mode and completely ignoring my GPU (Nvidia GeForce GT710).

#### Preliminary Debug

- **AVX Instructions**
  According to `journalctl` the "CPU does not have AVX or AVX2", therefore "disabling GPU support".
- **CUDA Compute Capability**
  The minimum compute capability supported by Ollama seems to be 5.0.
  There is also a proposal to add support for 3.5 but still not merged.
  However, the CUDA Compute Capability of my GT710 seems to be 2.x or 3.x.
  *Sources: [Add support for CUDA 5.0 cards](https://github.com/ollama/ollama/pull/2116), [Older CUDA compute capability 3.5 and 3.7 support](https://github.com/ollama/ollama/issues/1756).*
- **Memory RAM/VRAM**
  According to [Ollama GitHub page](https://github.com/ollama/ollama):

  > "You should have at least 8 GB of RAM available to run the 7B models, 16 GB to run the 13B models, and 32 GB to run the 33B models."

  Therefore, to run even tiny 1B models you might need 1~2GB RAM, which is more than the 1GB available at my GPU.

  However, some sources pointed out that there are some fine tuning in Ollama that might decrease the required VRAM:

  - "A lot of models have a very big context sizes configured and that's why they need a lot of VRAM.
    You can change the context size by making your own Modelfile [...] That way it needs less VRAM and is able run on more GPUs."
    *Source: [What kind of hardware does ollama support?](https://www.reddit.com/r/ollama/comments/17ekzvg/what_kind_of_hardware_does_ollama_support/?sort=old)*
  - "you can run an AI while loading it in either the VRAM, or the RAM, or even the internal drive.
    [...] Medvram stores part of the AI in the RAM, and lowvram stores part of it in the internal drive."
    *Source: [Some people are worried about ram and others about vram.](https://www.reddit.com/r/LocalLLaMA/comments/181d8u7/im_extremely_confused_about_system_requirements/?sort=old)*

#### Preliminary Conclusions

- My CPU does not have AVX instructions. Therefore, no matter how powerful is my GPU, Ollama
  will never enable it.
- The CUDA Compute Capability of my GPU is 2.x or 3.x. Which unfortunately is not currently supported by Ollama.
  At the moment, Ollama requires a minimum CC of 5.x.
- At the moment, RAM/VRAM are not yet an issue since there are some configs in Ollama
  that could be used to make it use less memory and/or partition the model between RAM/VRAM.

#### Questions

1. Are my preliminary conclusions correct?
2. If not, is it possible to make Ollama enable support of my GPU? How?

---

#### Additional Info

###### System Specifications

- **Operating System:** Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
- **Product Name:** HP Compaq dc5850 SFF PC
- **CPU:** AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 B97
- **RAM:** 8GB DDR2
- **Video Card**
  Product Name: NVIDIA GeForce GT 710
  Total Memory: 1024 MB
  CUDA Cores: 192
  CUDA Version: 11.4
  NVIDIA Driver Version: 470.223.02

###### Ollama Installation & Debug

As mentioned in the official site, "Install with one command":

```
root@debian:~# curl -fsSL https://ollama.com/install.sh | sh
>>> Downloading ollama...
######################################################################## 100.0%##O#-#                                                                        
>>> Installing ollama to /usr/local/bin...
>>> Creating ollama user...
>>> Adding ollama user to render group...
>>> Adding ollama user to video group...
>>> Adding current user to ollama group...
>>> Creating ollama systemd service...
>>> Enabling and starting ollama service...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/default.target.wants/ollama.service → /etc/systemd/system/ollama.service.
>>> NVIDIA GPU installed.
```

Therefore, considering the final message "NVIDIA GPU installed", it seems that Ollama properly enabled the GPU.

However, during Ollama execution, the GPU stays in idle:

```
root@debian:~# nvidia-smi
Thu Feb 29 21:18:38 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.223.02   Driver Version: 470.223.02   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:02:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 40%   46C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    315MiB /   981MiB |     N/A      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                           
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

According to `journalctl` the CPU doesn't have AVX instructions and therefore GPU will be disabled:

```
root@debian:~# journalctl -u ollama -f --no-pager
Mar 01 13:39:40 debian systemd[1]: Started ollama.service - Ollama Service.
Mar 01 13:39:40 debian ollama[588]: time=2024-03-01T13:39:40.385-03:00 level=INFO source=images.go:710 msg="total blobs: 5"
Mar 01 13:39:40 debian ollama[588]: time=2024-03-01T13:39:40.387-03:00 level=INFO source=images.go:717 msg="total unused blobs removed: 0"
Mar 01 13:39:40 debian ollama[588]: time=2024-03-01T13:39:40.387-03:00 level=INFO source=routes.go:1019 msg="Listening on 127.0.0.1:11434 (version 0.1.27)"
Mar 01 13:39:40 debian ollama[588]: time=2024-03-01T13:39:40.387-03:00 level=INFO source=payload_common.go:107 msg="Extracting dynamic libraries..."
Mar 01 13:39:46 debian ollama[588]: time=2024-03-01T13:39:46.158-03:00 level=INFO source=payload_common.go:146 msg="Dynamic LLM libraries [cpu cpu_avx cpu_avx2 cuda_v11 rocm_v5 rocm_v6]"
Mar 01 13:39:46 debian ollama[588]: time=2024-03-01T13:39:46.158-03:00 level=INFO source=gpu.go:94 msg="Detecting GPU type"
Mar 01 13:39:46 debian ollama[588]: time=2024-03-01T13:39:46.158-03:00 level=INFO source=gpu.go:265 msg="Searching for GPU management library libnvidia-ml.so"
Mar 01 13:39:46 debian ollama[588]: time=2024-03-01T13:39:46.162-03:00 level=INFO source=gpu.go:311 msg="Discovered GPU libraries: [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/tesla-470/libnvidia-ml.so.470.223.02]"
Mar 01 13:39:46 debian ollama[588]: time=2024-03-01T13:39:46.178-03:00 level=INFO source=gpu.go:99 msg="Nvidia GPU detected"
Mar 01 13:39:46 debian ollama[588]: time=2024-03-01T13:39:46.178-03:00 level=INFO source=cpu_common.go:18 msg="CPU does not have vector extensions"
Mar 01 13:39:46 debian ollama[588]: time=2024-03-01T13:39:46.178-03:00 level=WARN source=gpu.go:128 msg="CPU does not have AVX or AVX2, disabling GPU support."
Mar 01 13:39:46 debian ollama[588]: time=2024-03-01T13:39:46.178-03:00 level=INFO source=routes.go:1042 msg="no GPU detected"
```

###### Nvidia GeForce GT710 CUDA Compute Capability

*Source: [Your GPU Compute Capability](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)*

CUDA-Enabled GeForce and TITAN Products

- NVIDIA GeForce 710M (for notebooks): CC 2.1
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 740: CC 3.0
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 730: CC 3.5
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 730 DDR3,128bit: CC 2.1
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 720: CC 3.5
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 705*: CC 3.5

Therefore, it seems that GT710 is CC 2.x/3.x.